# How can I apply Logical Operator to 2 Select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pgadmin

I have 4 tables named `A, B, C, D`. I have `2 conditons to get the data`

`Condition 1`

```
Select *
From A, B, C
Where //All 3 tables are joined with conditions
limit 1; // Display 1 data at a time
```

`Condition 2`

```
Select *
From A, B, D
Where //All 3 tables are joined with conditions
limit 1; // Display 1 data at a time
```

What I am `looking for is to combine above 2 Select Statement` such that

`If Data Exists in Condition 1` then `Display Data` **OR** `Display Data from condition 2`

How can I acheieve above functionality?

Comment: `mysql` and `postgresql` are different databases, why have you tagged both?  *(Pick **one**.)*

Comment: on the second query do a WHERE NOT EXISTS(<your first query>)....and union query 1 to the new query 2

Comment: @Cato okay let me try that. Cant I use simply `OR`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
if exists(/*First query*/)
begin

/*FirstQuery*/

end

else

begin

/*Second Query*/

end
```

Comment: How can I use above approach in `js file`?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of

```
Select *
From A, B, C
Where //All 3 tables are joined with conditions
limit 1 // Display 1 data at a time
UNION
Select *
From A, B, D
Where not exists(Select *
From A, B, C
Where //All 3 tables are joined with conditions)
limit 1
```

Comment: This will not give desired output as in `2nd where clause` we are not defining `By what conditions we need data in 2nd WHERE CLAUSE`

Comment: Does it makes sense what I am trying to say?